# How to grab a number from a text file, while ignoring the word in front of it?

Tags: java, printwriter

So I have a .txt file with only this as the contents:

```
pizza 4
bowling 2
sleepover 1
```

What I'm trying to do is, for example in the first line, ignore the "pizza" part but save the 4 as an integer.

Here is the little bit of code I have so far.

```
public static void addToNumber() {

  PrintWriter writer;
  Int pizzaVotes, bowlingVotes, sleepOverVotes;

   try {
     writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("TotalValue.txt"));
     }
   catch (IOException error) {
     return;
     }


   // something like if (stringFound)
   //      ignore it, skip to after the space, then put the number
   //      into a variable of type int
   //      for the first line the int could be called pizzaVotes

        //   pizzaVotes++;

        //  then replace the number 4 in the txt file with pizzaVote's value
        //  which is now 5.
        //  writer.print(pizzaVotes); but this just overwrites the whole file.

        // All this  will also be done for the other two lines, with bowlingVotes
        // and sleepoverVotes.

      writer.close();

   } // end of method
```

I am a beginner. As you can see my actual, functioning code is very short and I don't know to proceed. If anyone would be so kind as to point me in the right direction, even if you just give me a link to a site, it would be extremely helpful...

EDIT: I stupidly thought PrintWriter could read a file

Comment: `PrintWriter` is only for *writing* - it doesn't *read*.

Comment: You must first **read** the data, **store** them in appropriate data structures, **process** them and only then **write** them back in the file. I suggest you write the part that writes to the file last.

Comment: After you create a code to read the data you can use a `regular expression` to get only the number, but this would let you to another problem: What if a line has more then one number e.g. `pizza 4 bowling 5` ...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for pointing that out -- these are new concepts for me and I didn't realize the massive error. Edited my question a bit

Comment: @Ingo I see, so I could use for example, Scanner first to read the file and then go from there

Comment: @JorgeCampos Ah. But if I know that each line in the .txt file has only one number, I take it that a regular expression would work?

Comment: @user2946455 yes definitely will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple actually. All you need is a Scanner, and it's function nextInt()

> ```
>         // The name of the file which we will read from
>         String filename = "TotalValue.txt";
>
>         // Prepare to read from the file, using a Scanner object
>         File file = new File(filename);
>         Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
>
>         int value = 0;
>
>         while(in.hasNextLine()){
>              in.next();
>              value = in.nextInt();
>              //Do something with the value here, maybe store it into an ArrayList.
>         }
> ```

I have not tested this code, but it should work, but the `value` in the while loop is going to be the current value of the current line.

Comment: However if I remove the Strings from the .txt file, it gets and saves the value just fine... the problem is I need to include the names in the file

Comment: put `in.next();` right before `value = in.nextInt();` as first line in the while loop and see what happens.

Comment: I was able to get it working with the addition of the in.next(); -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, so comment if you want some clearer advice

Here is a common pattern you'll use in Java:

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File(.....));

while(sc.hasNextLine(){
    String[] line=sc.nextLine().split("\\s");//split the string up by writespace
    //....parse tokens
 }
 // now do something
```

In your case, it seems like you want to do something like:

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File(.....));
FrequencyCloud<String> votesPerActivity=new FrequencyCloud<String>()
while(sc.hasNextLine(){
    String[] line=sc.nextLine().split("\\s");//split the string up by writespace
    //if you know the second token is a number, 1st is a category you can do 
    String activity=line[0];
    int votes=Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
    while(votes>0){
        votesPerActivity.incremendCloud(activity);//no function in the FrequencyCloud for mass insert, yet
        votes--;
    }
}


///...do whatever you wanted to do, 
//votesPerActivity.getCount(activity) gets the # of votes for the activity
/// for(String activity:votesPerActivity.keySet()) may be a useful line too
```

FrequencyCloud: http://jdmaguire.ca/Code/JDMUtil/FrequencyCloud.java

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is the use of an external class the only way to do it, or is it still possible otherwise?

Comment: Still possible otherwises. If you are only going to see the items once per file, you can do HashMap<String,Integer> votesPerActivity=.... then later do votesPerActivity.put(activity,votes). If you are going to see the items multiple times per file, you do  if(votesPerActivity.contains(activity){ votes+=votesPerActivity.get(activity);} votesPerActivity.put(activity,votes);

Answer (score 0):

String num = input.replaceAll("[^0-9]", " ").trim();

For sake of diversity this uses regular expressions.